# node-ffi module fail to load 32bit C dll - dynamic linking error

Tags: node.js, dll, 32-bit, dynamic-linking, node-ffi

I'm having sone trouble trying to load a C 32bit DLL with nodejs-ffi module. This is my code:

When running, node throws an error on Dynanic_library.js: 74 Dynamic Linking Error

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');
var path = require('path');

import idatabase = require('./IDatabase');
import idataset = require('./Dataset');

var dllpath = path.join(__dirname, '../../StoneBaseDLL.dll');
var dbpath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../database/metadata/metadata.db');

export class Stonebase implements idatabase.IDatabase
{
    dbHandler;
    dbConnection;

    constructor() {

        this.dbHandler = ffi.Library(dllpath, {
            'connect': ['void*', ['string']],
            'Execute': ['void*', ['string', 'void*']],
            'disconnect': ['void*', ['void*']],
            'EndOfResultSet': ['bool', ['void*']],
            'Next': ['void', ['void*']],
            'getNumberOfFields': ['int', ['void*']],
            'GetField_AsString': ['string', ['int', 'void*']],
            'GetField_AsChar': ['string', ['int', 'void*']],
        });

        this.dbConnection = this.dbHandler.connect(dbpath);
    }

    execute(query: string) {
        var data: Array<Array<string>>;
        var columns: Array<string>;
        data = [];
        columns = [];
        var i = 0;

        var dset = this.dbHandler.Execute(query, this.dbConnection);

        for (var j = 0; j < this.dbHandler.getNumberOfFields(dset); j++) {
            columns[j] = "column" + j;
        }

        while (!this.dbHandler.EndOfResultSet(dset)) {
            var line: Array<string>;
            line = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < this.dbHandler.getNumberOfFields(dset); j++) {
                line[j] = (<string>this.dbHandler.GetField_AsChar(j, dset));
            }
            data[i] = line;

            this.dbHandler.Next(dset);
            i++;
        }

        return new idataset.Dataset(data, columns);
    }

}
```

I'm using Typescript but I'm quite sure this has nothing to do with the problem

Thank you guys for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that your node is 32 bit? IF your node is 64 bit then switch to 32 and try again.

Comment: How do I switch to 32bit? Re-install the 32bit version?